# how can we remove closest div comes out of the parent div

Tags: jquery

Here I want to remove the closest div comes inside a foreach loop,the structure looks like this

```
<div id="add_new">
 <div class="form-group mb0 hhhh" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
       <?php foreach ($document_inf as $document_in){ ?>
        <div class="label1000">
            <input type="text" class="label100" required name="document_name[]" value="<?php echo $document_in;?>" >
         </div>
      <?php }?>
    <div class="col-sm-5 hhh">
       <div class="fileinput fileinput-new hh" data-provides="fileinput">
       <?php foreach ($document_info as $document_info){ ?>      
       <div class="h">

          <strong>
             <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="RCF"><iclass="fa fa-times">            </i>&nbsp;Remove</a>
          </strong>
       </div>
     <?php }?>
     </div>
</div>
```

Here when i click class `RCF` i want to remove the correspondent class `label1000` div.so for that i had done like this

```
$("a.RCF").click(function () {

       $(this).parents("div").find('.label1000').remove();
 });
```

when i done this the entire div with class name `label1000` is getting deleted[image]

Comment: I did not understand what's wrong with your code

Comment: The only potential issue I can see is that `parents()` goes up *every* parent element in the DOM, so if you have multiple containers with `.label1000` elements then that would be a problem. It's not clear exactly what you're asking, though.

Comment: Here i want the the correspondent input type with the class name `RCF` should remove

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Here what i want is the class label1000 corresponding to the anchor tag  is to be removed

Comment: Do you have multiple `.hhh` elements that hold `.label1000` elements?

Comment: @user_777 getting confused. Where is your corresponding anchor tag?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have multiple `.h` class and multiple `.label1000`.Here anchor tag can be seen with the class name `.RCF`

Comment: @MH2K9 corresponding anchor tag is visible inside class `.h`

Comment: Ok, and which `.label1000` element do you mean exactly by 'closest'? The first one?  The last one? All of them?

Comment: You want to say that if you click Nth position anchor, Nth position `.label1000` will be deleted. right?

Comment: @MH2K9 Yes that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments under the question it appears that you want to remove the `.label1000` element which matches the *index* of the clicked `.RCF` element.

In order to do that you can use `index()` to get the index of the clicked element, then `eq()` to select the `.label1000` element which matches that. Try this:

```js
$("a.RCF").click(function() {
  var $h = $(this).closest('.h')
  $('.label1000').eq($h.index()).remove();
  $h.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add_new">
  <div class="form-group mb0 hhhh" style="margin-bottom: 0px">
    <div class="label1000">
      <input type="text" class="label100" required name="document_name[]" value="A">
    </div>
    <div class="label1000">
      <input type="text" class="label100" required name="document_name[]" value="B">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 hhh">
      <div class="fileinput fileinput-new hh" data-provides="fileinput">
        <div class="h">
          <strong> 
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="RCF">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;
                Remove
              </a>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="h">
          <strong> 
              <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="RCF">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;
                Remove
              </a>
            </strong>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```